# How to redirect after sign_in using Devise

Tags: devise

When I sign in using devise I stay on same /users/sign_in page. Do I need to override Devise session controller? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

in your application_controller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def after_sign_in_path_for (resource)
    root_path # or whatever path you want! 
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: I tried this and put debugger here but unfortunately this piece of code is not touched by debugger

Comment: That's peculiar. Are you using the default Devise SessionsController to handle signing in and out?

Comment: Yes. Your code will work with custom Devise session controller?

Comment: I currently use it with the default controller, and it works fine. It's even referenced in Devise's Github page: "You can also overwrite `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_sign_out_path_for` to customize your redirect hooks." https://github.com/plataformatec/devise - I'm not sure why your code isn't picking it up, though.